# Return values from IN list that have no match in the table

Tags: postgresql

I have a query like below:

```
select case_id  from cases where case_id in  
('dddfc33c-71ef-4d8f-ad7c-506a11372d98',
 '414bf99f-2d44-4282-ac78-d82ea8754a78',
 '8f3e0be0-6c60-40ca-8683-d95d0294b223',
 '0434c8d3-0da3-40b6-b263-860432a44e4f');
```

If the `IN` condition matches 3 rows, I would like to get the 1 row which is in the `IN` condition list but not in the table.

Comment: It *always* helps to provide the actual table definition and your Postgres version. For the case at hand, the data type and its `NULL` / `NOT NULL` setting matter.

Answer (score 2):

Transform your input into a ***set*** *somehow*. Then apply one of the standard techniques to ...

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19364694/939860)

Here is a variant with `LEFT JOIN` / `IS NULL`.

```
SELECT t.case_id
FROM  (
   SELECT unnest('{dddfc33c-71ef-4d8f-ad7c-506a11372d98
                  ,414bf99f-2d44-4282-ac78-d82ea8754a78
                  ,8f3e0be0-6c60-40ca-8683-d95d0294b223
                  ,0434c8d3-0da3-40b6-b263-860432a44e4f}'::uuid[])
   ) t(case_id)
LEFT   JOIN cases c USING (case_id)
WHERE  c.case_id IS NULL;
```

`EXCEPT` (better `EXCEPT ALL` !) or `NOT EXISTS` have already been mentioned and should give similar performance. The essential part is to have an **index** on `codes(code_id)` and use the **matching data type**.

Your sample values are valid UUIDs, so `cases.case_id` should have the data type `uuid` (!). Then pass `uuid[]` or cast in Postgres.

It's typically simplest to provide a single array. The benefit over a list (like in your original `IN` list) or a set (like in a `VALUES` expression): it can easily be passed as single parameter to a prepared statement or stored function. Like:

```
PREPARE qry1(uuid[]) AS 
SELECT t.case_id
FROM  (SELECT unnest($1)) t(case_id)
LEFT   JOIN cases c USING (case_id)
WHERE  c.case_id IS NULL;

EXECUTE qry1('{dddfc33c-71ef-4d8f-ad7c-506a11372d98
              ,414bf99f-2d44-4282-ac78-d82ea8754a78
              ,8f3e0be0-6c60-40ca-8683-d95d0294b223
              ,0434c8d3-0da3-40b6-b263-860432a44e4f}');
```

Answer (score 0):

I used below and it worked

```
select unnest(array['dddfc33c-71ef-4d8f-ad7c-506a11372d98',
'414bf99f-2d44-4282-ac78-d82ea8754a78',
'8f3e0be0-6c60-40ca-8683-d95d0294b223',
'0434c8d3-0da3-40b6-b263-860432a44e4f',
'6e44fdc2-e3bd-4857-9ac6-6606a677c4c5')) case_id
except
select case_id::TEXT from ready_cases where case_id in 
('dddfc33c-71ef-4d8f-ad7c-506a11372d98',
'414bf99f-2d44-4282-ac78-d82ea8754a78',
'8f3e0be0-6c60-40ca-8683-d95d0294b223',
'0434c8d3-0da3-40b6-b263-860432a44e4f')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NOT EXISTS condition using the list of IDs as a derived table:

```
select case_id  
from (
  values 
    ('dddfc33c-71ef-4d8f-ad7c-506a11372d98'),
    ('414bf99f-2d44-4282-ac78-d82ea8754a78'),
    ('8f3e0be0-6c60-40ca-8683-d95d0294b223'),
    ('0434c8d3-0da3-40b6-b263-860432a44e4f')
) as ids(case_id)
where not exists (select * 
                  from cases c
                  where c.case_id = ids.case_id)
```